# How to remove space in between two ImageViews?

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my code below, how do i remove space between 'back' button and logo of screen? my screen looks like this

[image]

and i want to make like this

[image]

Please help me

```
 <LinearLayout

 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/border"

 android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@null"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:src="@drawable/back" />

 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/test_button_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:background="@null"
         android:paddingBottom="3dp"

        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/imagelogo" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_button_text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/test_button_image"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/test_button_image"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="San Diego Unified"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_button_text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/test_button_text2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/test_button_text2"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="School District"
        android:textColor="#000000" >
    </TextView>
 </RelativeLayout>

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/options" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: remove the paddings ??

Comment: remove this padding : android:padding="15dp"

Comment: if removing padding solced your issue, then I can make it as answer and you can accept it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Set Content to LinearLayout & set the **weight** value of childs.
>
> 2) Set the margins around Yours textViews of ImageViews. (Best way - > save it to dimensions file)

Comment: is work now i actuly use this termin backbutton android:padding="15dp" i resolve it now thnx for help

Answer (score 0):

Make your main layout a RelativeLayout instead of a LinearLayout.
You can then position your center RelativeLayout (with the logo and 2 textfield) 
with android:layout_centerInParent.
After that you can align vertically the backbutton to the left and the menubotton to the right of your centerlayout

Comment: confussing do u tell me in code edit????

Comment: i did but screen totally change if change linearlayout with  RelativeLayout

Comment: I just gave you a general solution, when you change the layout you have to make some other adjustments aswell