# how to move image and align it to right of screen

Tags: android

In my code image1 is show on left side but image test_button_image2 not move at right of screen what do i do? this is my screenshot

[image]

i wan tomake likie this

[image]

please help me how do I move image2 on right of layout?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


  <LinearLayout

   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/imagelogo2"

   android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/test_button_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/back" >
        </ImageView>

       <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/test_button_image2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"

      android:paddingLeft="5dp"
      android:paddingTop="15dp"
      android:src="@drawable/back" />

     </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lytContent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/txtCopyright"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         android:background="@drawable/border2" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/lytTitlebar"
        android:orientation="vertical" >



        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listMainMenu"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:listSelector="@drawable/listview_selector"
            android:dividerHeight="1dip"
            android:fadeScrollbars="true" />
        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove space in between two ImageViews?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330788/how-to-remove-space-in-between-two-imageviews)

Answer (score 0):

This layout is kinda messy, but from what I can see:

1. Your university's logo is set as the background of the layout (`android:background="@drawable/imagelogo2"`). It seems that you need to move it into a separate ImageView.
2. You have 2 ImageViews displaying the back button.
3. Please consider using margins instead of paddings. I think this would better fit what you're trying to do.